# Why I get error when I upload zip file to phonegap service?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

I try to create apk file using phonegap service.

Here is my config.xml file in my project:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="il.co.geomind.gilgalplay" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>sites</name>
    <description>
        app for sites mapping
    </description>
    <author email="jacklondon@ddd.com" href="">

    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>

    <icon src="images/icons/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icons/xxxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxxhdpi" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="images/icons/mdpi.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="images/icons/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="images/icons/ldpi.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="images/icons/mdpi.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="images/icons/ldpi.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="images/icons/mdpi.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

  <gap:platform name="android" />

  <gap:splash src="images/icons/screen-xhdpi.png"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.6" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.3.0" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5.0" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.12" source="npm"/>

</widget>
```

I make zip file from the project and make upload to the phonegap service I get this error:

```
Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin@2.5.0
```

Any idea why I get error above and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the source to Node Package Manager (source="npm"), you're telling PhoneGap Build to retrieve the plugin from that location, but "com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin, version 2.5.0" isn't actually there.

If we look on [npmjs.com for the push plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin), there are two plugin search results but as mentioned in the other Answer, it hasn't been updated for over 2 years and is even labeled "-deprecated".

Assuming you want a push notification plugin, I recommend trying to find an official one.  To do so, search for them by beginning with “cordova-plugin” coupled with whatever you’re looking for: "cordova-plugin-push". This led me [to this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-push-notification), which would probably work.

In your config.xml file, add a reference to it like so:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-push-notification" version="2.5.2" source="npm" />
```

I used version 2.5.2 since that's the latest version:[image]

For further reference, see my guide on [using NPM with PhoneGap Build](https://www.netkow.com/its-not-you-its-me-start-using-npm-for-phonegap-build-plugins-now/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin, which appear to be deprecated and hasn't had a release in 2 years.

Looks like you should try https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push instead which is the replacement for it

Comment: Any idea how I use it? How and where do I reference in my project?

Comment: There is an example app for the plugin, which you can create from a template, so you might be best trying that: phonegap create my-app --template phonegap-template-push (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md)

Comment: can't I just install specific js files to my project and referance then in config.xml file.I already has a project I only need to create apk file ?